# How to stream live-generated data from 1 backend (in Kubernetes) to multiple frontends

Tags: kubernetes, redis, socket.io, architecture, stream

I have a backend server (Node.js / Express) that I am deploying with Kubernetes. I have a system design question about how I should go about getting multiple clients to stream live-generated content (audio/text) from the same source.

### Summary of Problem

My basic use case (**existing**):

1. A client sends a request to the server
2. The server responds with a stream which is consumed by a client
   (Think ChatGPT, responding with a text stream after you ask it a question)

My question relates to the following **target use case**, which complicates things by adding more users:

1. Multiple clients are on a specific page of my website
2. One client sends a request to the server
3. The server generates a text stream, *but all users stream the received content* if they're on that page

My streams may be text or audio.

### What I've tried

If I make a server stateful, and save the stream object as a variable that can be re-accessed on future requests, then subsequent requests from the other clients can successfully access the same stream of the live-generated text/audio. But that approach won't scale horizontally due to the statefulness.

I have done quite a bit of research, but I need some feedback & suggestions. I was thinking I might use the following approach:

- When the initial user sends a request to the server, begin uploading serialized stream content to a messaging service (like Kafka or RabbitMQ - but I will probably use Redis Pub/Sub to start because I already have it in my stack)
- The initial request also triggers a Server-Sent Event or socketIO socket to notify the relevant clients that they need to stream something (along with a corresponding id). Each server in the cluster receives a message via the messaging service or Redis Pub/Sub telling it to send the event to its subscribed clients
- Upon receiving the message, all subscribed clients make a HTTP request with that id, which allows them to subscribe to the part of the messaging service where the serialized stream is being pushed. The stream content is forwarded to each client as it is generated (usually, the whole stream will take less than 10s to generate)

### What I want

I don't need code, just system design advice. And the simpler I can keep things, the better.